# Effect of fuzzy images/text on the user

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, text, image, trust

My logic in my head is saying if a page contains fuzzy/pixelated images or text then this will put an element of distrust in the users head.

This can occur from designers or developers using an image too small for the location and using CSS to increase it's size or by the use of a font that isn't designed to be made bold etc.

Are there any studies/papers about that explain the effect of fuzzy images/text on a user?

If anyone has come across this in their working life too, would be great to get a bit of info around it.

Answer (score 2):

- Nielsen & Norman have this [article](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/communicating-trustworthiness/) related to your issue, where it says:

  > Design quality: professional appearance feels solid; clear navigation conveys respect for customers and an implied promise of good service. **Typos or difficult navigation communicate disregard for the users.**
- They also have another, [similar one](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/trustworthy-design/), which says:

  > 4 out of the 5 participants who compared ... [two websites] ... judged [website 1] as more attractive and informational, and considered the pictures, fonts, and colors more appealing. When—as with these two sites—the **prices and offerings are fairly similar** between two companies, **the design of each website becomes a major deciding factor.**
- And then there is this quite new [study](https://www.brightlocal.com/learn/local-citations-trust-report/) by BrightLocal *(1,025 US-based consumers, conducted in March 2018)*, **showing that 50% of the participants lose trust when seeing poor quality images:**

  [image]